# how do I delete a file that goes into root?

Tags: lubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu in Windows 10 WSL2, without the VM(as VM box is not requred with WSL2) but it is really a pain to use.
So, I was told that I shouldn't use Root to do any file download or whatever.
The thing is even if I do it via a folder from a directory and do my things there, like

```
https://pastebin.com/kPyyQX23
```

It will still goes to the Root.
Now, my only solution is going back to cmd and forget about using Linux in Windows system.
But, for me to download the file I need, I have to get rid of the thing I downloaded and have crept to the root.

I hope someone can advise me how to get rid of that file in root.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry ... what is it that you are trying to do? You want to delete a file? Is this in Windows Subsystem for Linux? Is this in a virtual machine? If it's a virtual machine, are you using Lubuntu or is this a typo? How is it that you're downloading files to the root directory?

Comment: I need to get rid of the files that crept into /root/.nvm

Comment: Use `rm` to remove a file, you'll need elevated privileges, so use a `sudo rm /path/filename`

Comment: how do i find out the directory ? I didn't know that this Ubuntu on Windows is such a pain that it will always go to the root but where is the root?

Comment: Be aware `/root/` and root (ie. `/`) directories are different things.  `/root/` is a user directory (for the root account) where as the root directory is "/"

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you have not "downloaded the file to the root directory" at all.  I guess you're confusing two issues.  The "root directory" is the location `/`.  The "root user" is the system administrator, whose folder is `/root/`.  (i.e., in the directory "root", below `/`).

What you have done is that you're logged in as the root user.  I am not familiar with the Windows Subsystem for Ubuntu and I'm unsure if you can create another user and log in as that.  That's the first thing you should find out.  (And I can't help you with that since that is specific to the Windows Subsystem; an actual Ubuntu system would set up a default user that isn't root.)

The second thing that is happening is that you're downloading a file with `curl` and immediately running it with `bash`.  I downloaded that file myself and noticed that it's installing it in `${HOME}/.nvm`.  For `${HOME}`, it's substituting in "root".  Hence, you get the message "nvm is already installed in /root/.nvm".

To undo what you have done,

1. Go to `/root` by doing `cd /root`.
2. Remove what you've installed:  `rm -f -r .nvm`.

Then, create an account.  For example, see [these](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support) instructions.

Then, as that user, do what you're trying to do.

Also, note that the command you're typing is doing two things:  (1) downloading a file and (2) immediately running it.  You can do it in two steps as:

1. `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh >install.sh`
2. `bash ./install.sh`

I hope this helps...